# Regex that matches two or three words, but does no catpure the third if it is a specific word

Tags: regex, regex-look-ahead

I need to match a specific pattern but I'm unable to do it with regular expressions. I'm looking for people's name. It follows always the same patterns. Some combinations are:

1. Mr. Snow
2. Mr. John Snow
3. Mr. John Snow (Winterfall of the nord lands)

My problem comes when sometimes I have things like: `Mr. Snow and Ms. Stark`. It captures also the `and`. So I'm looking for a regular expression that does not capture the second name *only* if it is `and`. Here I'm looking for `["Mr. Snow", "Ms. Stark"]`.

My best try is as follows:

`(M[rs].\s\w+(?:\s[\w-]+)(?:\s\([^\)]*\))?)`.

Note that the second name is in a non-capturing group. Because I was thinking to use a negative look-ahead, but If I do that, the first word is not captured (because the entire name does not match), and I need that to be captured.

Any Ideas?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/6hdcqg/5) is some text to fast check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my two cents:

```
\bM[rs]\.\h(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:[\h-]\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*)\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cgoi01/1)

---

- `\b` - A word-boundary;
- `M[rs]\.\h` - Match `Mr.` or `Ms.` followed by a horizontal whitespace;
- `(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:[\h-]\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*)` - A capture group with a nested non-capture group to match an uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters and 0+ 2nd names concatenated through whitespace or hyphen;
- `\b` - A word-boundary.

Answer (score 4):

As it is a name of a person you could also check that the first letters of the  words be uppercases.

```
M[rs].\s[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+(?:\s\([^\)]*\))?)?
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/u3DA6A/1)

Answer (score 3):

This captures the first name in group 1 and the second in group 2if the second name exists and is not `and`:

```
(?<=M[rs]\. )(\w+)(?: (?!and)(\w+))?
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/xIHhApYJtxktPv).

---

If you want to capture the title as group 1 and the names as groups 2 and 3, change the look behind to a capture group:

```
(M[rs]\.) (\w+)(?: (?!and)(\w+))?
```

Answer (score 3):

Matching names is difficult, see this page for a nice article:

[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

For the examples that you have given, you might use:

```
\bM[rs]\.(?: (?!M[rs]\.|and )\w+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `M[rs]\.` Match either Mr or Ms followed by a dot (note to escape it)
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - Match a space (Or `\s+` if you want want to allow newlines)
  - `(?!M[rs]\.|and )` Negative lookahead, assert that from the current position there is not Mr or Ms or `and`  directly to the right
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/od2cRl/1)